# Avalanche - eth_getBalance - Converting the balance from hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: avalanche

## Context

Using the Avalanche Explorer, I selected a random address that has some AVAX in it:

https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/0xB9F79Fc4B7A2F5fB33493aB5D018dB811c9c2f02/transactions

At the time that I looked that address up, the AVAX balance is around 39,166:

[image]

## Code

I'm using the following REST call to retreive the balance of that address:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getBalance",
    "params": [
        "0xB9F79Fc4B7A2F5fB33493aB5D018dB811c9c2f02",
        "latest"
    ],
    "id": 1
}'
```

At the time that I made the call, it returned the following:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x8868dc30a5d07460032"}
```

## Question

As you can see, the balance comes back as:

```
0x8868dc30a5d07460032
```

What's the recommended way to convert that to the decimal balance?

Feel free to point me to the right place in the [developer documentation](https://docs.avax.network/) if this is discussed there.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to fetch those request within a web app? If so, you can use ethers library that will decode all of the function result data for you (not just the numbers) https://docs.ethers.io/v5/

Comment: @PeterSlaný, for now just a command line tool but eventually/potentially, yes from a web app. Thanks for that reference!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Javascript here is the snippet:

```js
async getBalance(address) {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            id: 1,
            method: 'eth_getBalance',
            params: [
                address,
                'latest'
            ]
        })
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    return parseInt(data.result, 16) / Math.pow(10, 18);
}
```

You can make the same calculation with other languages or whatever you use.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you simply divide by 18.

Here's some PowerShell function `Get-AVAX-Balance` that will retrieve a balance given an address:

```
function Convert-Hexadecimal-to-Decimal ([string]$hexadecimal)
{
    $str = '0{0}' -f ($hexadecimal -replace '^0x')

    [decimal]([bigint]::Parse($str, [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowHexSpecifier))
}

function Get-AVAX-Balance ($address)
{
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc' -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{
        jsonrpc = "2.0"
        method = "eth_getBalance"
        params = @($address, "latest")
        id = 1
    })

    (Convert-Hexadecimal-to-Decimal $result.result) / [math]::Pow(10,18)
}
```

```
PS C:\> Get-AVAX-Balance '0xB9F79Fc4B7A2F5fB33493aB5D018dB811c9c2f02'
37667.049457617898011819
```